# How to track a specific link using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I want to track following link:

[www.example.com/james-levine?nameKey=jQQacwXh2X](http://www.example.com/james-levine?nameKey=jQQacwXh2X)

Comment: How to use regex for this url?

Comment: Regex implies patterns. You don't indicate a pattern there, you indicate the actual URL. What pattern would you like to use for the url?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Page View trigger where the page URL contains the desired part of the link.
[PageView trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnkPL.png)